# how to Plot for the same asset different time frames price charts in one chart

Tags: pine-script

I would like to plot for the same asset the monthly, weekly and daily price action in 1 chart (ploting as lines instead of bars to make it cleaner).

The idea is to get a chart where the monthly is like the "main price line", then the weekly line fluctuates around the monthly price line, and the daily price line fluctuates around the weekly line.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function to request data from other time frames.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

weekly_close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", close)
monthly_close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", close)

plot(weekly_close, color=color.green)
plot(monthly_close, color=color.red)
```